# How to display a photo on a Tkinter App from a URL using canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
import io
import base64

try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
    from urllib.request import urlopen
   


def display_poster(image_url, x, y):
    # image_url = "http://i46.tinypic.com/r9oh0j.gif"

    image_byt = urlopen(image_url).read()
    image_b64 = base64.encodebytes(image_byt)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_b64)

    # create a white canvas
    cv = tk.Canvas(bg='white')
    cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

    # put the image on the canvas with
    # create_image(xpos, ypos, image, anchor)
    cv.create_image(x, y, image=photo, anchor='nw')

def btn_clicked():
    display_poster("http://i46.tinypic.com/r9oh0j.gif", 630, 350)
```

I have tried the **base64 package** solution but its not working.
It would be nice if someone could help me out with the **pakages** i need to import and the **function** to display the image using **Canvas**.

Comment: The example link is invalid and so a JPEG image is returned which is not supported by tkinter `PhotoImage`.

Answer (score 0):

use this snippets, its work fine :

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
#import base64
import io
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Weather")

link = "http://i46.tinypic.com/r9oh0j.gif"

class WebImage:
    def __init__(self, url):
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
            raw_data = u.read()
        #self.image = tk.PhotoImage(data=base64.encodebytes(raw_data))
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    def get(self):
        return self.image

img = WebImage(link).get()
imagelab = tk.Label(root, image=img)
imagelab.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i need the answer using canvas...grid is not applicable in my project due to some other stuff am using..can u convert this to canvas code